# Adjuntar ficheros mailto-html

Tags: php, html

Necesito enviar correos electrónicos en mi aplicación PHP pero no se deben enviar automáticamente sino que debe abrirse el cliente web predeterminado para poder ver el contenido del mensaje y poder modificarlo si de da el caso. He estado utilizando la función de html `mailto`.

El motivo por el que abro el cliente mail en lugar de mandar el email directamente con PHP es porque el cliente al cual le estoy desarrollando la aplicación me lo ha pedido así y como se suele decir, "*el cliente siempre lleva la razón*". Visto que no hay otra forma de abrir el cliente mail que no sea con mailto, mi pregunta es:

**¿Cómo puedo adjuntar uno o varios ficheros con mailto?**

Explico lo que hace un poco mi aplicación: es un gestor de tareas donde al crear una tarea se debe enviar un correo a los usuarios a los que se les ha asignado esta tarea. A la tarea se pueden adjuntar archivos que son los que se deben de enviar por email. Esos archivos se guardan en una carpeta en C:, el directorio que he puesto en `mailto` (C:\hola.txt) es de prueba pero el fichero hola.txt si está en el.

Utilizando

```
mailto:'.$emails_invitados.'?subject='.$nombreTa‌rea.'&body='.$observacionesT‌​area.'&attachment="C:\hola.txt" '
```

He conseguido que se abra el cliente de correo pero el archivo no se adjunta correctamente.

Comment: Hola Felipe y bienvenido! ¿El archivo es local? Si es así es tan sencillo como hacer esto: `mailto:email@domain.com?subject=TituloMensaje&body=TextoMensaje&attachment=\\ruta\al\fichero`. No estaría de más poner la parte del código concreta para ayudarte de una manera más específica :)

Comment: Vale aclarar que PHP trabaja en el servidor y, como tal, no puede manejar nada del cliente. Lo que estás intentando hacer es propio del navegador o, si quisieras hacerlo en PHP, sería a través de un formulario web.

Comment: El código para el mailto que utilizo es este:    mailto:'.$emails_invitados.'?subject='.$nombreTarea.'&body='.$observacionesTarea.''
                . '&attachment="C:\hola.txt" '

Comment: Evitaría usar `mailto` directamente. Puede crear una mala experiencia de usuario si no se tiene definido un gestor de email (el usuario pulsará sobre el botón/enlace y nada pasará). Aparte de eso, por motivos de seguridad no puedes abrir/enlazar automáticamente un fichero local desde tu página web (necesitas que el usuario lo seleccione de forma activa). Te recomendaría que usases un modal con un formulario en lugar del `mailto`.

Comment: @FelipeRuiz En vez de enviar el correo desde la PC del usuario, ¿no te conviene enviar el correo desde el servidor haciéndolo desde el código de PHP? Si hay que adjuntar un archivo del usuario, haría un formulario que permita subir el archivo al server y luego se adjuntaría. Ej: http://blog.jpgallego.com/php-mail-enviar-correo-con-un-fichero-adjunto-mediante-php-2/

Comment: No tiene sentido que PHP (del lado del servidor) interactue del lado del cliente. Mira esto por ahí te puedo ayudar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231125/automically-open-default-email-client-and-pre-populate-content

Answer (score 0):

> **mailto** permite especificar sujeto y el cuerpo , así como cc campos.

**Por ejemplo:**

```
mailto:username@example.com?subject=Subject&body=message%20goes%20here
```

El usuario no necesita hacer clic en un enlace si lo fuerza a abrirse con JavaScript.

```
 window.location.href = "mailto:user@example.com?subject=Subject&body=message%20goes%20here";
```

> Tenga en cuenta que no hay una sola manera, estándar en el que navegadores / clientes de correo electrónico manejan los enlaces de correo (por ejemplo, campos de asunto y el cuerpo pueden ser desechados sin una advertencia).
>
> También existe el riesgo de que los emergentes y bloqueo de anuncios, el software anti-virus, etc. puede bloquear la apertura de los enlaces de mailto forzada.

**Ejemplo 2.**

**JQuery**

```
 $(function () {
      $('.SendEmail').click(function (event) {
        var email = 'sample@gmail.com';
         var subject = 'Test';
         var emailBody = 'Hi Sample,';
         var attach = 'path';
         document.location = "mailto:"+email+"?subject="+subject+"&body="+emailBody+"?attach="+attach;
         });
     });
```

**HTML:**

```
   <button class="SendEmail">Send Email</button>
```